# android studio: how to download sdk update

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I just downloaded the Android Studio and am probably not seeing something obvious.

How do I download an update for the sdk?  I'm using Windows 7.

I have opened the Settings window and opened the Android SDK pane.  It shows several items as installed and one with update available.  I checked the corresponding checkbox.  Now what?

I tried clicking Apply and OK but nothing happens.

Here's what the popup looks like:
[image]

Comment: You also have to agree to the license. There should be a checkbox.

Comment: I've agreed to several licenses but there is no such request on this page.  I added an screen shot of the popup, see above.;

Comment: I don't know if this is really the answer to your question, but it will work: click on "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" and it should launch an interface where progressing with the updates is more obvious.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it actually did provide a good alternate solution - worked. Thanks, though.  I'll let this question stand, in case someone does figure out what's choking Android Studio.

Comment: I have had this happen, but not often - does the window appear but in the background?